# Can I tell foreman to reload the web app every time a request is made so I can develop decently?

Tags: node.js, foreman

A web app I am writing in JavaScript using node.js. I use Foreman, but I don't want to manually restart the server every time I change my code. Can I tell Foreman to reload the entire web app before handling an HTTP request (i.e. restart the `node` process)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's an adjusted version of Pendlepants solution. Foreman looks for an .env file to read environment variables. Rather than adding a wrapper, you can just have Foreman switch what command it uses to start things up:

In .env:

```
WEB=node app.js
```

In dev.env:

```
WEB=supervisor app.js
```

In your Procfile:

```
web: $WEB
```

By default, Foreman will read from .env (in Production), but in DEV just run this:

```
foreman start -e dev.env
```

Comment: This didn't work for me on Heroku-- the `.env` file was never loaded.  Made a separate Procfile, instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560241/how-to-use-nodemon-with-env-files

Answer (score 7):

You can use [rerun](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) for this purpose

You might implement just 2 commands for this:

1. gem install rerun
2. rerun foreman start

Then rerun will automatically restart process after any change in your files.

Comment: Wouldn't this be slow, fully restarting everything in the procfile on every file change?

Comment: I currently use [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) to this, it's not really a big deal to restart the app on every file update. It's very convenient.

Answer (score 6):

If you use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)
 , you can do

```
nodemon --exec "foreman start"
```

Comment: I tried this but it get stuck at "[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart", the server dont start again

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't with Foreman so much as it's with how node doesn't reload code on new requests. The solution is to use an npm package like [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) along with an environment wrapper for Foreman.

First, install supervisor:

```
npm install -g supervisor
```

Then, write a wrapper shell script that Foreman can call:

```
if [ "$NODE_ENV" == "production" ]; then
  node /path/to/app.js
else
  supervisor /path/to/app.js
fi
```

Set the wrapper script's permissions to executable by running `chmod a+x /path/to/wrapper_script.sh`

Lastly, update foreman to use the wrapper script. So in your `Procfile`:

```
web: /path/to/wrapper_script.sh
```

Now when you run Foreman and your node app isn't running in production, it should reload on every request.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like Peter Ehrlich's comment on the original question deserves to be an answer on its own. I think a different Procfile for local/dev is definitely the best solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10790514/133720

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to install anything new if you use node-dev.

Your .env file loaded from Procfile:

```
NODECMD=node-dev
```

Your Procfile:

```
web: $NODECMD app/server.js
```

Your foreman command

```
foreman start -e dev.env -p 9786
```

And in your production env (heroku) set an environment variable:

```
NODECMD=node
```