# How to use nodemon with .env files?

Tags: javascript, web-services, node.js, environment-variables, development-environment

I am using an .env file to hold environment variables for the server. This works if I run the server with foreman start. But it doesn't work with nodemon.

I would like to use nodemon instead because it restarts automatically when you modify the server. How can I get nodemon to work with .env files?

Comment: I've been using .env files with [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package and really useful but I have a trouble if I change some variable on the .env file and restart the process (e.g. using rs command on console) any new changes on the .env file are not taken in account

Comment: There are implications with _watching_ .env file, which are documented in the FAQ: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/faq.md#nodemon-doesnt-restart-on-env-change Some readers might come here because of friction from that.

Answer (score 43):

1. Install [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) `npm i dotenv`
2. Create `.env` file and your variables inside
3. Add the script to execute

   ```
   "dev": "nodemon -r dotenv/config ./app/index.js " or
   "start": "node -r dotenv/config ./app/index.js "
   ```
4. Run the app using `npm run dev` or  `npm run start`

Comment: hmm, this did not seem to work for me when using Typescript with nodemon, or possibly in combination with extension `-e` flag.

Comment: It works for me using nodemon (3.0.2) and dotenv version 16

Answer (score 33):

I have a **production** Procfile with:

```
web: node web.js
```

So I have created a Procfile_dev file with:

```
web: nodemon web.js
```

And when I am at development environment I run:

```
$ foreman start -f Procfile_dev
```

It works like a charm and doesn't affect production.

Comment: With Express the Procfile_dev would be: `web: nodemon ./bin/www`

Answer (score 27):

You can get nodemon to directly use the .env with the following command

```
$: env $(cat .env) nodemon app.js
```

Be aware that you'll have to restart it if you make changes to .env and it won't like it if there are any spaces in your .env file.

Comment: There is a problem with this approach if any of your variables inside have JSON value. Example: `JSON={"a": "b"}`, because of doublecuotes escaping.

Answer (score 15):

This will do it,

```bash
nodemon  -w . -w .env index.js
```

How it works:
**"-w ."** tells nodemon to watch the files in the current directory
**"-w .env"** tells nodemon to watch the .env file
**"index.js"** is just the file to run when changes occur (could be anything)

Comment: Confirm that it is still working in 2023

Comment: This will **NOT** solve the issue of this question. The parameter `-w` is a watch parameter, it means `nodemon` will reload the server on `.env `change, but it will **NOT** read/interpret the `.env` file then load the variables. It solves another issue, from the author of nodemon : https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/main/faq.md#nodemon-doesnt-restart-on-env-change

Answer (score 13):

With recent versions of Node (since io.js 1.6), you can pass it the `-r` flag to require a module on start. This lets you directly load `.env` by using nodemon's `--exec`:

```
nodemon --exec 'node -r dotenv/config'
```

This requires the npm package [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to be installed.

Comment: Or just `nodemon -r dotenv/config`...?

Answer (score 8):

Place your local configuration variables in the .env file and run foreman along with nodemon using the following command

```
$ foreman run nodemon web.js
```

Comment: This is a great solution since it also doesn't force you to have a `Procfile` if you don't want one.  The alternative is to use the `start` [script section](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html) in your `package.json` file, which gets used by `npm start` and `nodemon`.  And if you use [Heroku](http://heroku.com) for production, it now generates a `Procfile` on deployment that uses `npm start` as well.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I'm using TypeScript and the `.env` file is used for development only. I wanted my code to be decoupled from the `.env` file and I didn't want to `import 'dotenv/config'` anywhere in my code. This is my solution:

My nodemon config:

```json
{
  "watch": [
    "src",
    ".env"
  ],
  "ext": ".ts",
  "exec": "ts-node -r dotenv/config ./src/index.ts"
}
```

My NPM script:

```json
"start:dev": "nodemon"
```

In this solution `ts-node` requires dotenv, which sets up the environment variables before the main app starts. This means that nowhere in my code do I need a `import 'dotenv/config'`. `dotenv` can become a dev dependency, and this also prevents dotenv to be loaded at all once the code is deployed.

Comment: Assuming you don't use nodemon in prod then you wouldn't have dotenv available though?

Answer (score 3):

Thread necromancy!

Use [grunt-env](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-env) to load environmental variables from your heroku config.

Comment: This helped me use my .env file in my Gruntfile.js.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config src/server.js dotenv_config_path=dev.env dotenv_config_debug=true",
    "start:dev": "nodemon --exec \"npm start\""
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**In Three steps**

1. Creating the file on root folder > .env

```
# .env ======
PORT=5000
WHO_AM_I="Who Knows"
```

2. Install the dotenv
3. Run below command

```
"dev": "nodemon -r dotenv/config src/app.js"
```

> #### You can access the your defined variables using > process.env.varible_name

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run Typescript in `nodemon` *and* require a *particular* `.env` file with `dotenv` then you can do:

In `package.json` scripts:

`"dev": "nodemon -r dotenv/config src/myApp.ts dotenv_config_path=/path/to/your/env/file",`

And a line in `nodemon.json` to tell `nodemon` to use `ts-node` when encountering Typescript extensions:

`"execMap": {"ts":  "node -r ts-node/register"},`

This is useful for using a development `.env` file say `.env.development.local` for local dev work and leave the main `.env` file for live production variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use the -w key to specify nodemon what to watch additionally.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "env-cmd nodemon -w app -w *.js -w .env server.js"
}
```

Don't forget rerun *npm run dev*

Answer (score 1):

in `package.json`:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js -w . -w .env -e js,mjs,json,env",
    ...
  },
...
```

assuming `index.js` is located at `./src` and `.env` file is located at root.

`npm run dev` now:

```
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.* .env
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json,env
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget `dotenv` or anything, just use this param :

```
nodemon --env-file=.env index.js
```

It supports multiple files with overwriting:

```
nodemon --env-file=.env --env-file=.env.local index.js
```

From the author of nodemon:

https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/2153#issuecomment-1880021184

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Procfile

Change: web: node app.js to web: nodemon app.js

Answer (score 0):

To load the dotenv package and any declared .env vars into the environment, you can do the following:

```
nodemon -r dotenv/config myapp.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `cross-env` for environments.

`npm i cross-env`

set `package.json`.

"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/app.js",
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev nodemon --exec ts-node src/app.ts",

`npm run start` OR `npm run dev`