# How to use nodemon/grunt with .env files?

Tags: node.js, unix, gruntjs, foreman, nodemon

I am using an `.env` file to work with foreman, but am trying to configure nodemon to start my server using grunt, because I enjoy how nodemon restarts when files become modified.

I am trying avoid having an `.env` file for foreman AND having environment variables stored in my `~/.bash_profile` for nodemon. Instead, I would like to configure my `.env` file to work for both cases.

I found some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560241/how-to-use-nodemon-with-env-files), and the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11962552) should work for grunt.

My `.env` file is of JSON format, which should flatten environment variables via concatenation (see [here](https://github.com/NodeFly/node-foreman)).

When I run the following command `$ env $(cat .env) nodemon app.js`, I receive the following error: `env: {: No such file or directory`.

Anyone have an idea of what the problem may be? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest filing this at http://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/new - but I'd also say that there's environment config support in nodemon as of 1.0.9 - though I'm not 100% sure it'll solve what you want.

Basically you put a `nodemon.json` file in your home directory, and have:

```
{
  "env": {
    "USER": "remy",
    "PORT": "8000",
    "ETC": "etc"
  }
}
```

An example of the config can be [seen here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md) and a few more [details here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/#config-files).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried using the nodemon. But I've figured out how to do restart the server using foreman.

Define a key on your Procfile to run your application with node-supervisor

My proc file have a dev key that is like this: `dev: node-supervisor -w .,lib/ webserver.js`

The -w option is a comma separated list of the folders that you want to watch.